# Resize Infragistics GanttChart task with the mouse

Tags: winforms, charts, infragistics, gantt-chart

I loaded a custom `DataTable` into an `UltraChart` of type `GanttChart`.

The data loads successfully.
Do you know if it possible to add support for mouse resize(drag) to the tasks that show up into the chart?
I have not been able to figure out if this is supported by the `Infragistics` control.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In this forum post](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/3577.aspx), an Infragistics employee states that this is not implemented (as of Feb '08), but may be doable handling `FillSceneGraph`.